# Print When Expression in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to do a simple expression in iReport, but whatever I try seems has given me an error.  It seems like such a simple thing to do, but whenever I try to do anything in Java it takes me about 20 tries to get it right.

All I'm trying to do is show a subreport when the value of an integer field is not zero.  I am using the Print When Expression for the subreport control.

Here's a few (of the many) things that I've tried:

`$F{count}!=0`

`$F{count}!=Integer(0)`

`!$F{count}.compareTo(0)`

Obviously my Java sucks.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: "$F{count}.intValue() != 0" as well?

Comment: I get this error when I try that: `Cannot cast from boolean to Boolean value`

Comment: @lkdg - I wrapped `new Boolean()` around your suggestion and it works: `new Boolean($F{count}.intValue()!=0)`.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.  I like it better than the solution I came up with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new Boolean($F{count}.intValue()!=0)
```

Glad that I could help.

Comment: Note that the wrapping is not necessary when you select "groovy" as the scripting language (instead of default "java"). Tested with iReport 3.0.0 and Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

w00t!  35th time's a charm.  I finally got the following expression to work.  If anyone can tell me why, I would appreciate it.

```
new Boolean($F{count}.compareTo(new Integer(0))!=0)
```

Comment: So this should work then: $F{count}.intValue() != 0 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE

Comment: I wrapped new Boolean() around your original suggestion and that worked.  I think I like that better.  :)  Thanks for the help.