# How can I compare dates in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to compare dates in iReport ? I want to use the "Print When Expression.."

Something like : `$F{date_from_table} <= $F{another_date_from_table} ? true : false`

I tried : `($F{date_from_table}.compareTo($F{another_date_from_table}) < 0) ? "to aqui" : "nao to"`

and `( $F{date_from_table}.getTime() <= $F{another_date_from_table}.getTime() ) ? true : false`
It should work .

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens if you try: `$F{date_from_table}.before($F{another_date_from_table}) ? "1" : "2"`?

Comment: I got blank page ! It happens nothing ! ( Don't generate the PDF ).. The navegator page comes blank with nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in iReport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256124/how-to-compare-dates-in-ireport)

Answer (score 1):

That last syntex should be correct. That being said looking through my old code sometimes I find myself instantiating the variables as longs first.

```
new Long($V{date_from_table}.getTime()) <= new Long($V{another_date_from_table}.getTime()) ? true : false
```

This is the best answer I can give without knowing the IReport version number or language you are using. To find the language right click on the top level of your report in the "Report Inspector" and go to properties, by default it is Groovy but a majority of the community switches to Java for familiar syntex.

Comment: I'm sorry ! My iReport is 5.6.0... Integrated with PHP and PHPJasperXML ! I tried as you said... And the navegator just shows a blank page, It don't generate the PDF ... I don't know what to do anymore... ! I Already changed the language to Java . Thanks.

Comment: Well I would have to say that your date comparison is correct then. Something bust be wrong somewhere else. Personally I am on a older version so I won't be the most help but it looks like some people had luck with wrapping the entire statement in a "new Boolean(ternary statement)" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731262/print-when-expression-in-ireport. Some people also had luck with returning Boolean.True : Boolean.False instead of the traditional true : false. Also, you keep saying you get a blank page, are you hiding the iReport output window? You should be getting errors.